# not showing Android And AVD manager in eclipse

Tags: android

i have installed Andorid SDK...i installed Android Plugin also..but eclipse not showing Android And AVD manager and it is also not showing ANDROID in windows->preferences also...help me out..

Comment: you are not properly install the android sdk...once install as per the procedure in google docs.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, I just updated some eclipse modules. And when I restarted it, the two android related options no longer appear in the preferences... I tried reinstalling the android packages but still the same.

Answer (score 83):

I know by now you must have figured it out on your eclipse menu bar go to

1. window
2. customize perspective
3. command group availability tab
4. on the check box android SDK and AVD manager check it
5. click on ok

That should work.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But those are already ticked. What do u think I should do? I'm working on Win8 on a vm with 8 GB of Ram. Please help me. I have tried many solutions recommended on S.E. None of them has worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Select the Window->Customize Perspective->

In the options the Android SDK and AVD will be disabled.
You cannot enable them directly from this tab.

Go to the **Command Groups Availablility Tab** and **Select Android SDK and AVD Manager.**

Answer (score 7):

Help --> Install New Software then

add  this link adt - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

---

Please check [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) also

Answer (score 3):

This problem also occurs when in the Java EE perspective.  Open the Java perspective and the menu items should appear.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Use java perspective. Window -> open perspective -> other.. 
Select Java.

Answer (score 3):

Click on Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab. Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and hit the OK button

I have used it and it works fine with any eclipse version. #user1450537

Answer (score 2):

If under linux make sure you install sdk & avd with root rights or "Android" wont show under command group availability tab !

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above but only

`Help --> Install New Software`

then use this link `adt - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

which worked for me .

Now `avd` is showing up and I can add devices.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse Neon,
click on window--> customize perspective.
then click on the "Action Set Availability Tab" 
now you should be able to check "Android SDK and AVD Manager"