# Android SDK not showing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I have installed also i have installed ADT Plugin but when creat new project it does not show android project.I have also tried to reinstall the ADT plugin but it says they are already installed.

Comment: This was asked a while ago.  I just installed all of the Android stuff tonight, and this other thread gave me the answer that you were looking for also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110330/not-showing-android-and-avd-manager-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the API('s) you need/want with SDK Manager?

Comment: yes i have downloaded API when all the other things are downloaded through manager