# Android ADT is not recognized in Eclipse Neon.2

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, adt

I have downloaded ADT Plugin for Eclipse. I don't see Android anywhere either when creating a new project, Preferences or "Customize perspective"

I have searched for the answer but I couldn't find it. The only thing that I didn't try is opening "command group availability" tab mentioned in forum [not showing Android And AVD manager in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110330/not-showing-android-and-avd-manager-in-eclipse) because I can't see it at my setup.

I'm using Eclipse Neon.2 with JDK jdk1.8.0_121. I didn't add a PATH variable in my system. Not sure if I have to or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that either Eclipse Neon.2 stopped supporting ADT or that it has issues with it. I went back to Eclipse  Neon.1 and I can find Android references all over, so I think the issue is something to do with Eclipse Neon.2.

Thanks to all of you who tried to help.

### UPDATE:

It appears that for Neon.2 there is a separate package for Android that you can find here:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neon2

Answer (score 1):

Android ADT doesn't seem to work for me in Neon too (same errors and long time search on startup without results)

There is a new Eclipse Android dedicated IDE now at https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neon2 Must be installed in a separate folder with separate workspace (and renamed if needed) and all existing Android projects can be moved there. Afterwards i uninstalled ADT from the original Eclipse folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already installed neon2 and I don't have any other version eclipse. I do have however Android studio installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is Installation Instructions for Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.6 (Neon)
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.6

Comment: Kurt thanks but I already tried it and didn't work. I'm using Neon2 with neon files. could that be the issue?